# как получить текст с выбранного option

Tags: javascript, jquery

как получить текст с `option:checked` и записать это значение в `<span>`. Я написал скрипт но он работает не корректно, вместо того чтобы добавить новый елемент к уже существующим например: один(уже было) я выбрал два и в поле должно быть - `<span>один</span>`, и добавить вот этот Один новый елемент - `<span>два</span>` - а у меня скрипт снова добавляет один и получаеться `<span>один</span><span>один</span><span>два</span>` как это можно исправить?

js:

```
 $(".subway-location").change(function() {
            $(this).children("option").filter(":checked").each(function() {
                var x = $(this);
                console.log(x);
                var b = x.text();
                $("#metroDistance").css("display", "block");
                $("#metroDistance .info__item").append("<span class='distance-option'><span class='metro-name'>"+ b + "</span><input type='text' data-id='metro_distance'></span>");
            });
        });

<select class="subway-location">
<option>один</option>
<option>два</option>
<option>три</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так надо реализовать?

```js
 $(".subway-location").change(function() {
           var b = 'test';
           b= $(this).find('option:selected').text();
             $("#metroDistance").css("display", "block");
                $("#metroDistance .info__item").append(
                "<span class='distance-option'><span class='metro-name'>"+ b + 
                " </span><input type='text' data-id='metro_distance'></span>");
                
                
            
        });
```

```css
#metroDistance {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="subway-location">
<option value="1">один</option>
<option value="2">два</option>
<option value="3">три</option>
</select>

<div id="metroDistance">
   <div class="info__item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вы пытаетесь добавить спан в уже имеющуюся секцию.
Вот пример как записать выбранную опцию селектора в тэг **span** и добавить к имеющемуся элементу html блока.

Прошу заметить что 
$('.mydiv').empty(); очищает элемент с классом .mydiv

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myselect').change(function() { 
    var value = $('#myselect option:selected').text();
    $('.mydiv').empty();
    $('.mydiv').append('<span>'+value+'</span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
<div class="mydiv">
</div>
```